# Properties of Legendre Symbols and Quadratic Reciprocity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

### I'm still a little bit confused about solving these types of problems. I have the formulas but still not able to apply them properly:

Use properities of the legebdre symbol and quadratic reciprocity to evaluate the legendre symbols:

$(\frac{-30}{127})$, $(\frac{-30}{131})$, and $(\frac{-30}{137})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Factor and reduce".  $$\left(\frac{-30}{127}\right) = \left(\frac{-1}{127}\right)\left(\frac{2}{127}\right)\left(\frac{3}{127}\right)\left(\frac{5}{127}\right).$$

There are special theorems for $-1$ and $2$.  Then quadratic reciprocity works for the others:

$$\left(\frac{3}{127}\right)= -\left(\frac{127}{3}\right)=-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=-1.$$

And so on.

Comment: Remark on typo above: should be $(\frac{-30}{127})$. Unluckily edit requires more than one char change :-)

Comment: @Maestro13  Got it, thanks.